# What is the behavior of date/time fields regarding daylight saving time?

Tags: datetime, fields, database, timezone

A user located in São Paulo/Brasil is on the UTC-3 timezone. As I write this post it is actually UTC-2 because of daylight saving time.

That means that records created today will have the value of the current hour plus two. User saves a record at 9 AM, then on the database the value is of 11 AM.

After DST ends, the value will remain as 11 on the database. But what value will the user see when they check the "created at" date on the record page? 8AM is the technically correct value for the current timezone, but the record was created on DST, at 9 AM. Will they see 8 or 9 on the record page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce stores record in UTC format, based on users timezone it is displayed on UI. Even in user record, you will see the timezone is updated on that day when daylight saving gets started.

Comment: So they will see the time as 8AM (considering my example)?

Comment: It will be 8AM, everything will be shown on user's current timezone (on the day, user is looking the record) defined in user's record.